# $wpdb select date range of posts

Tags: wp-query, wpdb, sql

0
down vote
favorite
Using this SQL query to sort users by how many votes(meta key) their posts have received.

```
<?php


                        global $wpdb;


                        $results = $wpdb->get_results ( "
                           SELECT u.display_name as name,
                            ( SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value)
                              FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm
                              WHERE p.post_author = u.ID
                              AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
                              AND pm.meta_key = 'epicredvote'
                              AND p.ID = pm.post_id ) as votes
                              FROM wp_users u
                              ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 20
                        " );

                        foreach ( $results as $result ) { 


                          echo "{$result->name}: {$result->votes} votes<br>";

                        }
                ?>
```

Never really worked with a direct SQL query in wordpress before like this, it was always the wp loop or variations thereof.

Anyway, this will display the username + their score (total).

I'd like to do is limit this to a date range of posts, say a week.

I think it'd be possible to use strtotime to do this, but I'm not sure of how.

```
  $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 days'));
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-8 days'));
```

So to get posts in the last 7 days? Googled around but can't find much.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:- Full code that isn't working for some reason.

```
<?php


                        global $wpdb;

                         $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 days'));

                         $weekly = $wpdb->get_results ( "
                      SELECT u.display_name as name,
                        ( SELECT
                          CONCAT_WS('/',
                            SUM(CASE WHEN p.post_date < '$date2' THEN pm.meta_value ELSE 0 END),
                            SUM(pm.meta_value))
                          FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm
                          WHERE p.post_author = u.ID
                          AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
                          AND pm.meta_key = 'epicredvote'
                          AND p.ID = pm.post_id ) as votes
                          FROM wp_users u
                          ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 20
                    " );


                        foreach ($weekly as $result) {
    $name = $result->name;
    list( $weekly_vote, $total_vote ) = explode( '/', $result->votes ? $result->votes : '0/0' );
    // do stuff with $name, $weekly_vote, $total_vote ...eg
    echo  $name, '<br>', ' Weekly Vote: ', $weekly_vote,'<br>', ' Total Vote: ', $total_vote, '<br>', '<br>';
}
                    ?>
```

Comment: Have you seen the date query for WP_Query yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have the answer, just add `$date2` to the inner sql where clause:

```
AND p.post_date > '$date2'
```

to get last week. To get a particular week, use

```
AND p.post_date < '$date1' AND p.post_date > '$date2'
```

where eg

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-07-04 +1 days'));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-07-04 -8 days'));
```

To return weekly/total votes, you could put the test into the select clause:

```
                    $results = $wpdb->get_results ( "
                       SELECT u.display_name as name,
                        ( SELECT
                          CONCAT_WS('.',
                            SUM(CASE WHEN p.post_date < '$date1' AND p.post_date > '$date2' THEN pm.meta_value ELSE 0 END),
                            SUM(pm.meta_value))
                          FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm
                          WHERE p.post_author = u.ID
                          AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
                          AND pm.meta_key = 'epicredvote'
                          AND p.ID = pm.post_id ) as votes
                          FROM wp_users u
                          ORDER BY votes+0 DESC LIMIT 20
                    " );
```

And then output results as desired:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $name = $result->name;
    list( $weekly_vote, $total_vote ) = explode( '.', $result->votes ? $result->votes : '0.0' );
    // do stuff with $name, $weekly_vote, $total_vote ...eg
    echo 'Name: ', $name, ' Weekly Vote: ', $weekly_vote, ' Total Vote: ', $total_vote;
}
```

Comment: How would I roll both into the query so I could display total in last week AND the total?

Comment: Well I suppose you could move the date test into the select clause, eg `SELECT CONCAT_WS('/', SUM(CASE WHEN p.post_date < '$date1' AND p.post_date > '$date2' THEN pm.meta_value ELSE 0 END), SUM(pm.meta_value)) AS votes` etc.

Comment: Can you update your answer to write that within the context of my code?

Comment: Having trouble with the concat, want something like this:- `CONCAT_WS('<div>VALUE HERE</div>/ this week',`, 'VALUE HERE' being the number of votes. Reading about SQL concat_WS now.

Comment: It might be easier/nicer to do that using php, `list($weekly_vote, $total_vote) = explode('/', $results[$idx]['vote']); $str = '<div>' . $total_vote . '</div>' etc`

Comment: Can you update your answer with it? this sql stuff really goes over my head despite reading the documentation.

Comment: After some testing that new output doesn't appear to respect the DESC order for the vote sum.

Comment: I edited my original question to reflect the code I'm using. Users are ranked seemingly randomly, not based on either weekly or total votes.

Comment: Ok forgot about the sorting! - I'll edit the answer again to replace the '/' with a '.' and force numeric sort (+0) to sort by weekly - to sort by total switch the order of the SUMs.

Comment: Ah, that's amazing, bonger! Thanks. I've asked around a bunch of people about this and you're one of the only ones who's been good with the SQL queries. I accepted your answer, really helped! Just one question as an addendum, I've been trying to do something like this `<li>
   <a href="' . get_author_posts_url( $author->ID ) . '">' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' , $author->ID ) . '</a>
   (' . $author->posts . ') ' . get_avatar( $author->ID , 40 ) . '
  </li>` to display avatar and link to profile urls, but it doesn't seem to accept standard WP markup. Ideas?

Comment: If I understand you you need to select u.ID along with (or instead of) u.display_name in the outer query and use `$result->ID` instead of `$author->ID` in your markup.

Comment: Ah damnit, I can't get it working. I'll create a new question for it. Thanks again!